# how to exclude file or directory from zip command in bash

Tags: bash, zip

I have a file called .ignore which include files or directories such as:

file1
dir/

so suppose I have a directory with this .ignore file under it. I want to zip all files or dirs excluding all things defined in .ignore file. My bash command would be :

```
zip -r test.zip * -x dir/\* package.json
```

without read from .ignore file.

so if I want to read from .ignore file. I can do something like this but does not work.

```
zip -r test.zip * -x $(echo $(cat .lambdaignore))
```

Anything wrong ?

Comment: Note `$(echo $(cat .lambdaignore))` is equivalent to `$(cat .lambdaignore)`, so you can remove echo. Also, is your first command (`zip -r test.zip * -x dir/\* package.json`) working?

Comment: yes it works. zip -r test.zip * -x dir/\* package.json

Comment: Then check the output of `cat .lambaignore`. If the output is `dir/\* package.json` then the command `zip -r test.zip * -x $(cat .lambdaignore)` should make the same compression as your first command: `zip -r test.zip * -x dir/\* package.json`.

Comment: not exact the same

Comment: it does not recognize the `dir` directory

Comment: $(cat .lambdaignore)
zsh: no such file or directory: dir/\*

Comment: if I run $(cat .lambdaignore) separately, it complains.

Comment: Perhaps reading the section on Command Substitution from bash manual can help: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html